# Django + ( CherryPy or Tornado) for deploying in Windows?

Tags: django, windows-xp, nginx, cherrypy, tornado

i finally come to run django on windows under cherrypy and tornado using: [django_cpserver](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/mar/25/serving-django-cherrypy/) and [django-tornado](https://github.com/rjdj/django-tornado)

And here is my question:

- is it OK to deploy the django project using one of them? mean; no security problem, no speed problems...
- how to use nginx to reverse proxy the static files? i always hear about this technique, but i only find Unix-Like configuration, how to do this on windows?
- NB: as you can see i dident mention mod_wsgi, i will not use apache, i dont know why i hate it without testing it! but it seems that the mod_wsgi is the lonly way to modify the wsgi file to avoid server restarting (all my information are what i've read from internet...), am i wrong? if so, how to do that with cherrypy?

Comment: Your statement 'but it seems that the mod_wsgi is the lonly way to modify the wsgi file to avoid server restarting' doesn't make a great deal of sense. No matter what Python hosting system you use, if you modify your code the application needs to be restarted to pick it up. Python isn't like PHP. Where as in PHP you can change individual files and they will be automatically picked up on next request without a restart you just can't do that in Python because of how Python works.

Comment: Actually you *can* do that with `mod_wsgi`. You can have it do a sort of "soft reset" every time it detects that a file has changed, where it just reloads the python scripts and doesn't restart the whole server. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Comment: Scratch that. From the link I just posted: "Thus, the only way one can have code changes picked up on Windows is to restart Apache as a whole."

Comment: Graham : so the reloading is only when it's a developpement server, when deploying it's another thing?
Clueless : so here is again the problem of windows :'(

Comment: Auto reloading is only recommended for development servers because the constant checks puts a load on the server and for a production server you don't want it reloading when you are half way through applying changes as the resultant code might not run and you would have screwed your production system. Touching the WSGI script or reloading Apache allows you to control exactly when new code loaded, which is much safer for production.

Comment: but sometimes it's a code problem, look at the example i put above, it will work, but will not update!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this one will not update!
`return HttpResponse(a)` if you put `a = "now it's %s" % datetime.datetime.now()`
is really bad, you should put

```
HttpResponse("now it's %s" % datetime.datetime.now())
```

it seems that it's not only a problem of which server to use! but also how to use variables! sorry if i was out of the question, but i found this and i said maybe it will help!